# Alternative button for turning a laptop "ON"

Tags: laptop, button-remapping

I have a Dell 6400, and the power button has trouble working sometimes, I was wondering if there is anyway to swap its function with a some of the buttons I don't use, like the front media buttons or the MediaDirect button (which also turns the laptop on but in a low-level media-only mode). Or to fix the laptop power button itself?

Thank you so much, I tried to google this one out and looked for software, but I guess this is more of a hardware issue? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated : )

This is what the laptop looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with the osther comments from Molly and Niek but would add one thing.

I have seen some Latitude D820/830 that get some dirt or something under the power button and then work sometimes and not others.  Have you removed the cover that runs just below the screen (assuming it is same, can't find a parts diagram)and had a look at the actual button that is usually at the top of the main board?

Comment: this is actually the right answer.  laptop buttons (well, most computer/gadget buttons) are two-piece: the button itself is soldered to a PCB, and the thing you press is actually a cover.  it's often that cover that's damaged or not making contact correctly.  if under warranty, let the repair shop handle it; if not, find a service manual, disassemble the case, and clean it out good.  (if it's the actual button that's broken or worn-out, yes, soldering will be involved...)

Comment: I've had this problem with many many Dell laptops. The Precision M60 and Inspiron 8600 have also had this problem.

Comment: THANK YOU O_O  
wow i fixed it under 10 minutes : )  
for people having this problem, this is what i did->   
  
i used this procedure to open the power button cover http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins6400/en/sm/hingecvr.htm#wp1123881  then with two very small watch screwdrivers i rubbed off the oxidized contacts of the green electronic board and the corresponding antler like contacts on the case itself. Of course very carefully so that i wouldn't break them. Now not only the power button works but the led lights, WiFi blutooth and Numlock turn on as well :D thank you so much!

Comment: just to clarify, you should turn your computer off while doing this, and i used two screw drivers because i would position one under the antler like contact and use the other to scrap it, this way making sure the pressure wouldn't cause it to break. Be Careful!

Comment: And, of course, remove the laptop battery, just to be on the safe side ;-)

Comment: that's very true haha!

Answer (score 6):

there is no software solution, your only hope is soldering.

Comment: go on then, do it! and get a move on, less than 300 karma points and you can sort out all the little annoyances yourself :)

Comment: Done. <3. Keep up the good work, and ty.

Answer (score 2):

As Molly said, there would be no software solution for this.

Is this laptop still under warranty? If so, please do consider sending it in. In most cases, they should be able to fix this for you for free. (However, please do make backups of all your important data before sending it in. Some factories format all machines (or even replace the harddrives) by policy before even beginning on hardware work)

Otherwise, I am afraid the only way would indeed be by soldering.

Answer (score 0):

if bios supports hotkey power on but might drain battery faster because it would have to supply power to the keyboard even when it's off

Comment: How does this answer the question?